# Similarity of matrices to a power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A^{10}$ is similar to $B^{10}$, is the true that $A$ is similar to $B$?

So I now that when $A$ is similar to $B$, then $A^{10}$ is similar to $B^{10}$ 
since $A^k = P^{-1} B^k P$

Would this be the right approach?
$A^9 = (P^{-1} B^{10} P)^{-1}$

$ = P^{-1}B^9(P^{-1})^{-1}$

and continue on...

Comment: (-1)^2=1^2, but -1 is not similar to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question was:

If $A^{10}$ is similar to $B^{10}$, is it true that $A$ is similar to $B$?

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$  and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$

Then $A^{10}=B^{10}=0$

Now proceed.

Comment: neither A^10 or B^10 is invertible, thus they are not similar

Comment: No. $A^{10}$ and $B^{10}$ are similar, since  $A^{10}=0=P^{-1}0P=0=P^{-1}B^{10}P$ with $P=I$

Comment: My bad, I see what you mean

Comment: but $A,B$ are not similar, as similar matrices have same rank, where $rank(A)=1\ne 0=rank(B)$

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not similar, since from $A=P^{-1}BP$ it would follow that $A=0$.